# Pandas Shuffle sequential data with batch size

Tags: pandas, shuffle, sequential, batchsize

Here is my question,

Think about a time series as a pandas data frame, for example a market's price data, i want to shuffle it but not each row separately, i want to have a group of rows as one sequential part and then shuffle these sequentials and get back the data frame from it. for our example, lets say i want to keep the data for a whole week as it is inside a sequence, but shuffle the week information around and then combine these weekly data (not changed internally) together to get new chart out of it ! the final product i want is the same structure as the original, with these sequenced parts shuffled.

I'm totally new to pandas and python. Can anyone help and guide me for an efficient way of doing it specially on big data sizes?

thanks

Comment: We would need a [MCVE].

Comment: I really don't know how to give you a minimal example of like 200 candle stick data but, here is how the data table looks

Comment: I really don't know how to give you a minimal example of like 200 candle stick data but, here is how the data table looks  the headers are : ['Timestamp' 'Open' 'High' 'Low' 'Close' 'Volume'] so, each row will be the data needed to draw one candle stick on a financial charts. let's say i want to keep indices 0-10 together, and 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50 and finally 50-60. meaning that, each batch is 10 candle's data. how many batches did we get? 6. now shuffle these 6 batches and finally merge them back.

Comment: the batching and shuffling is NOT that hard, I already implemented it, But the main issue, is to re adjust the time stamp column to make the new data "look" sequential in total like an original market data. this way, i could get 200 day's of data, shuffle, and voila, you have totally new 200 days of data. although the new data may not look like how the real market's behave, but choosing proper section of real data and shuffling the proper batch sizes, should work for generating real like market info.

Comment: so, the question is actually two folded : a) what is the most optimized and fast way to achieve the new shuffled tables b) how to fix the discrepancy of the timestamp column to make it look like real time following data rows (needed for part of my stuff)